# Can Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1 generate classes for stored Procedures?

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, reverse-engineering

Are there any method to generate classes for stored Procedures in my DB when I used Reverse Engineer code first that provided by Entity Framework Power Tools CTP1?

Comment: What do you mean by "generate classes for stored Procedures"? Generate Entity classes, map stored procedures?

Comment: I mean generate classes as Edmx file Generate classes for selected  Stored Procedures .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it wont be generated for you but with a mild bit of effort you can integrate them.
You can simply generate from your tables, and then return an entity inside your repository layer:

```
        public Customer GetById(int id)
        {
            return_context.Database.SqlQuery("Proc_GetCustomer @customerID", new SqlParameter("@customerID", id));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to have code used to call your stored procedures generated by any tool use EDMX and database first approach.